# How do I find a location based on the longitude and latitude that the user enters?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.1

I'm currently working in Android Studio. Below is the code in my java file, so far I'm able to find a location based on an input which I specified within the code. I would instead like to have 2 separate edit text locations where I can input the longitude and latitude, then press a button to find the location.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration;

public class HelloMap extends Activity
{

    MapView mv;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_map);


        Configuration.getInstance().load
                (this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));

        mv = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map1);

        mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mv.getController().setZoom(14);
        mv.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(51.05,-0.72));
    }}
```

I'll also include my activity main in case it's any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/map1"
        tilesource="Mapnik"
        />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:id="@+id/latet"
    />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/longet"
        android:layout_below="@id/latet"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lattv"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/longtv"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm really not sure how to do this so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is connect your TextView's in the Activity itself and then have a button action to perform the action you set, this is a rough example.

Just update your textviews to be EditText, and add a button with the same Id as in the findViewById()

```
MapView mv;
EditText latitude;
EditText longitude;

Button showLocationButton;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_map);


    Configuration.getInstance().load
            (this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));

    mv = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map1);
    latitude = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lattv);
    longitude = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.longtv);
    showLocationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showlocationbtn);

    showLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    showLocation(Double.parseDouble(latitude.getText().toString()),  Double.parseDouble(longitude.getText().toString()));
                }
            })

    mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mv.getController().setZoom(14);
    mv.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(51.05,-0.72));
}}

private void showLocation(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    mv.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude));
}
```